# Decimals are in wrong place in latitude and longitude in Excel

Tags: excel, table

Somebody gave me an Excel table and the latitude and longitude had the wrong place for decimals. Is there a workaround to fix the problem? I am pretty much stuck trying to figure it out. Here is the example of what I am talking about:

[image]

The latitude and longitude should be like this:

3854.6 = 38.546, -10612.68 = -106.1268

Comment: And you don't divide by 100 because...

Comment: That works ...I use =CELL#/100 and it is perfect nicely..but I have to make sure the decimal are in the right position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a formula to divide by 100.

[image]

Comment: +1 but I would use =IF(ABS(A2)>360,A2/100,A2) just to be on the safe side. ABS(A2) accounts for negative values and > 360 (or > 90 for N/S) detects that a value isn't already in range.. then just to be extra safe import the table into MS Access ensuring field names have no spaces or punctuation, before trying to utilize the data; Access tables are more stable than Excel spreadsheets due to strong typing of cell values.

Comment: I googled earlier today and didn't work so  this one I haven't seen so I will give this try.

Answer (score 1):

What I have also noticed that Latitude values in your table can have different length before a dot for example `3854.6` and `391.119`. Moreover, IMHO your original values look more like text rather than real numbers.

Therefore, with the usage of the following formula, you can adjust your Latitude and Longitude values.

For Latitude values

```
=IF(FIND(",";VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;".";",")))=5;VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;".";","))/100;VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;".";","))/10)
```

For Longitude values

```
=IF(FIND(",";VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D2;".";",")))=7;VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D2;".";","))/100;VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D2;".";","))/10)
```

The output will look as following

[image: Output1]

---

As was previously specified in a comment by [@Hans-Erren](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/142597/hans-erren), if the value `391.119` should be `3901.119` instead, means that `0` was missing then use a different formula

```
=IF(FIND(",";VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;".";",")))=5;VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2;".";","))/100;VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B3;".";",");FIND(",";SUBSTITUTE(B3;".";","))-2)&","&"0"&SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B3;".";",");LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3;".";","))-FIND(",";SUBSTITUTE(B3;".";","))+2);",";"")))
```

[image: Output2]

Comment: Thank you but this is kinda of hard and complicated for a person who doesn't work in Excel much ....

Comment: what do you think will be a better "workaround"? processing with pandas for instance? It is just that much complicated as much as the input data represented. And it directly responds to your comment "but I have to make sure the decimal are in the right position".

Comment: It has nothing to do with yours it just if someone needs it really quick and the one I did was way easier and faster... but if you have lots of them like this then probably your might be better way and doesn't need right it away